# How to make 2 unrelated entities (two repository) run in one project at the same time ? Is it possible?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to make 2 entities (that's not related) in one project. i'm using Java springboot to connect to mysql database. so what's the best way i can do? because i tried to make 2 repository but i only succeed 1 of them. another one is giving me an error. its giving me error even it's actually fine when i run the query in mysql workbench

in my repository (AccountRepository.java) that's not working, i put something like this:

```
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Accounts, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT applicationPassword FROM Accounts where applicationName = 'myApp'")
    String findPasswordApp();
}
```

in the entity file (Accounts.java), i put something like this

```
@Entity
public class Accounts {
    @Id
    private Integer accountID;
    private String applicationName;
    private String applicationPassword; 
    public void setAccountID(Integer accountID) {
        this.accountID = accountID;
    }

public void setApplicationName(String applicationName) {
    this.applicationName = applicationName;
}

public void setApplicationPassword(String applicationPassword) {
    this.applicationPassword = applicationPassword;
}

public Integer getAccountID() {
    return accountID;
}

public String getApplicationName() {
    return applicationName;
}

public String getApplicationPassword() {
    return applicationPassword;
}
}
```

but it's giving me error. what i wanted from this entity is that i can check the value (read) in database that i already put it manually in mysql workbench.

and here is the table query that i execute first in mysl workbench

```
CREATE TABLE Accounts (
    accountID int,
    applicationName varchar(255),
    applicationPassword varchar(255)
);
```

and also here is when i succeed inserting data into it:

```
INSERT INTO Accounts (accountID, applicationName, applicationPassword)
VALUES ('1', 'myApp', 'password'));
```

Is there anything wrong with my code ? please help

Edit: i try to cover up with try catch on this line 'String password = accountRepository.findPasswordApp(); ' and that's giving me exception like 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

here is my full exception :
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.deliverMessage(CommsCallback.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.handleMessage(CommsCallback.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.run(CommsCallback.java:206)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 
    '

Comment: what´s the exception being thrown ?

Comment: i try to cover it with try catch and the exception says' java.lang.NullPointerException' . But i dont know why. because i run the query on mysql workbench and its working fine

Comment: try to debug and find out if `accountRepository`reference is null... if so check bean wiring / dependency injection of accountRepository

Comment: Please, post more information about your stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your repository is missing an annotation or isn't in a package being scanned. I have projects with 10s of repositories, so that's definitely not an issue, and your HQL in the @Query annotation seems somewhat okay.

There's no reason those 2 wouldn't work together, so I'm guessing your @Autowired field for the repo throwing the error is null at runtime. You likely merely forgot an annotation. Do you not have an @Repository annotation on top of the AccountRepository? Does @ComponentScan in your main class or configuration not have the package containing it?

If either of those things are missing that's your problem. Could you edit it with the full text of the exception?

Comment: i have another class (mainRepository.java) which has no @Repository annotation and it's working fine. i just copied the mainRepository and renamed it to AccountRepository

Comment: Is it in another package? Do a System.out.println(repoFieldName==null) in the class you're autowiring it into and add a @PostConstruct to the method to see if it's null...

Comment: i just add @Autowired above the private AccountRepository accountRepository; 
 as you said and its working fine (no more error) and what i found out is that the table is actually create itself so i dont need to execute new table in mysql workbench. So thanks for your answer :)